# Stencil build crashes when using jsonwebtoken

Tags: jwt, stenciljs

If I use jsonwebtoken in a stencil component, the build will crash with: [ ERROR ]  Node Polyfills Required

Add this code in a stencil component, and then build the project.

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
var token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, 'shhhhh');
console.log(token)
```

I tested this on both Windows and Mac and the error is the same.

Comment: Looks like that package is meant for NodeJS, not the browser, see https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/339#issuecomment-292812077

Comment: I can use jsonwebtoken package in React. It conflicts only with Stencil.